# Differentiate link on each ajax call

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem, show extracted publications database where every publication I have a button to add it to favorites.

[image]

But to click any button, the response of the ajax call returns me as if you had clicked all at once.

[image]

Code link:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-add" data-id="{!! $aviso->id !!}"> 
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></i> 
 </a>
```

JS Code:

JS code ajax call:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.btn-add').on('click', function(e) {

   var data = $(this).data('id');

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '{!! url("add-fav") !!}',
     data: { 'id' : data },
     dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data){
          if(data.message == 'ok')
          {
              $('.btn-add').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>')
          }
    }
})

  e.preventDefault();

 });
});
```

As mentioned above, the icon to run the ajax call, change, but in all publications.

If the answer instead of $('.btn-add') use $(this), the icon does not even change.

As I can achieve the result? That adding a favorite, only the icon that publication change?

Thanks for you help. Greetings From Chile.

Comment: You are updating glyphicon for all elements with class "btn-add". Define $(this) before ajax request - var that = $(this); then replace -  $('.btn-add').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>') with -   $(that).html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>').

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I fixed the code as you have said and now everything works perfectly. Greetings from Chile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cache your JQuery object:

```
$('.btn-add').on('click', function(e) {

var $btn = $(this);
```

And in success function:

```
$btn.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help friend, was precisely what was wrong with my code. Greetings from Chile.